# iptables to block all websites

Tags: debian, iptables, firewall

I have Debian 7, and I want to block all websites in my computer, unless my email, using IPTABLES or others firewall.

How can I block all website, include http and https too.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
iptables -I OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
iptables -I OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
iptables -I OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp -d youremailsiteIP/32 --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp -d youremailsiteIP/32 --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
```

where youremailsiteIP is the IP address of your mail site

Comment: this iptables will block https too?

Comment: Yes, but... it doesn't really block http or https. It blocks the ports that they most commonly use: http - port 80, and https - port 443. However, some sites use non-standard ports, and those will not be blocked by the above. For example: `http://example.com:8080/` or `https://example.com:8443/`